# post to aws lambda not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a page in cloudfront that contains this js:

```
const url = "https://..private..";
const myForm = $( elements ).serialize();
$.post( url, myForm, () =>
{
    alert("success");
})
.done( ( data ) =>
{
    alert( "success2: " + data );
})
.fail( (error) =>
{
    console.log( JSON.stringify(error ));
    alert("fail:" + error);
});
```

The code always lands in the fail path.  But there is no error object, and no other variables or objects to look at in the Chrome debugger, local and global are all empty.

**UPDATE**: I added the console log for error, and it shows: `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

This is the end part of my lambda function.  The logs show that I'm going through the success path, and data is getting inserted into the DB.  I've tried the callback with and without a status code.  I never get the return in the browser since I switched to ajax.

```
// insert into the DB
dynamodb.put( insertData, ( err, data ) =>
{
    if( err )
    {
        context.done('error putting item into dynamodb failed: ' + err );
        console.log('error putting item into dynamodb failed: ' + err );
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(" db insert success ");
        // this worked for a form submit, but not ajax post
        //callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: { "retVal": true } });

        let success = true;
        callback(null, { "body": JSON.stringify(success) } );
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** I also tried adding the error object to my lambda, from the suggested links, but there was no change in return value at the browser. I put the following code in the success path and Cloudwatch logs captured it as an error, just like the docs say it will.  However, this made no change to what the browser received.  argh!

```
var myErrorObj = {
         errorType : "InternalServerError",
         httpStatus : 500,
         requestId : context.awsRequestId,
         trace : {
             "function": "abc()",
             "line": 123,
             "file": "abc.js"
         }
     }
     callback(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
```

This might also be a clue:  The URL after the fail, has the post data shown as if it were a GET.
`https://hidden.cloudfront.net/index.html?workOrder=123&ESID=123&userId=...`

Comment: (1), Could you please check whether you throw the error from the Lambda function. It seems your callback does not include an Error object as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html . (2), assuming your Lambda function is exposed to the js in CloudFront via API Gateway, please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html to make sure whether your API endpoint handles the error response coming from Lambda and returns the correct HTTP status code to the client.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The logs show "db insert success", so err is not set.  I can cause err to be set by sending malformed data, so I know each path works.  The browser is getting: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be related to how I was submitting the form.
My HTML button was type **submit**:
`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>`
Even though I didn't have an action defined in the `<form>` it was still causing the page to reload.  And thus my page was out of sync with the response from the server.

The fix in HTML, remove the type and set an ID for jQuery usage:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Submit form</button>`

In JS, bind a click handler to the button like normal:

```
$( "#submitButton" ).click( ()=>
{
 ...
});
```

Pretty fundamental error when I look back on it. Hope this helps someone.